# Error Seting Spf for mail Server

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

I try using spf record to reduce email spoofing , that cause my domain blocked by others .
I have 3 mail server :
       mail.mydomain.ac.id
       mail.a.mydomain.ac.id
       mail.b.mydomain.ac.id
We can sent & receipt email to others or betwen them.
I use these spf command :

```
    v=spf1 a mx -all
```

I am not sure , is that correct or not . When I tried to test these spf using  spf checking tools , here is the result :

evaluating v=spf1 a mx -all ...
   Results - record processed without error.

The result of the test (this should be the default result of your record) was, 
   ambiguous . The explanation returned was, SPF Ambiguity Warning: No A records found 
   for: mydomain.ac,id

What should i do to fix these error ?

Thank you very much for any suggestion & help .

Comment: That error message has a comma where there should be a period.  Is that a typo in the question or in the original error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things here.  First, the error means that you have `a` specified in the SPF record, but there is no `A` record in your DNS entries, so either create an address record for the base domain or remove `a` from the SPF record.

Second, you mention that you have multiple servers that send, but `mx` is the only other entry in the SPF record as an authorized sender.  This means that all of those servers that can send mail should be listed within your domain's `MX` records.  If they are not part of the domain's `MX` records, you will need to list their individual IP addresses as part of the SPF entry to let others know they are authorized (`v=spf1 mx ip4:1.2.3.4 -all` if, for example, the IP address for `mail.a.mydomain.ac.id` were `1.2.3.4`).

Comment: thankyou Mr scott , your answer given me a picture of these problem

Comment: Mr Scott , as your suggestion, I create spf like these :
v=spf1 mx ip4:1.2.3.4 ip4:11.22.33.44 ip4:22.33.44.55  -all  
and when I test the SPF record , the result is :                record passed validation test with pySPF (Python SPF library)!

Comment: Mr Scott, sorry if bother , after adding these spf into DNS record , and then I try to check using mxtoolbox , for mx and ip4 have passed the test , but there are fail in : -all . Is there something missing ?

Comment: `-all` is part of the SPF standard, so there should not be an error there unless there is a typo or something in the SPF entry.  If the error persists I would contact mxtoolbox and inquire as to what specifically is throwing off their testing utility.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an A record for mydomain.ac.id in DNS

Answer (score 0):

FYI - When you've completed your DNS record entries, you can send a test email to mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com to verify proper setup. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

One cause of the issue is having the MX record valued with an IP address instead of a domain name.

Having MX=1.2.3.4 is wrong.
Having MX="mydomain.com" + A record mydomain.com="1.2.3.4" is correct.